# Why is createTheme (Material UI) not working for me here?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm trying to customize the default theme. But when I run the app the page gets blank and nothing appears instead I've got some error on the console. When I remove `<ThemeProvider theme={theme}></ThemeProvider>` attribute everything appear again. Below I'm sharing code from `App.js` and `console` log.

```
import CssBaseline from "@mui/material/CssBaseline";
import { makeStyles, ThemeProvider } from "@mui/styles";
import { createTheme } from "@mui/system";
import React from "react";
import Header from "../components/Header";
import SideMenue from "../components/SideMenue";
import "./App.css";

const theme = createTheme({
  palette: {
    primary: {
      main: "#333996",
      light: "#3644b126",
    },
    secondary: {
      main: "#f83245",
      light: "#f8324526",
    },
  },
});

const useStyle = makeStyles({
  appMain: {
    paddingLeft: "320px",
    width: "100%",
  },
});

function App() {
  const classes = useStyle();

  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <SideMenue />
      <div className={classes.appMain}>
        <Header />
      </div>

      <CssBaseline />
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
}

export default App;
```

This is the error from the console. I've no idea what causing this.

```
Paper.js:95 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '4')
    at Paper (Paper.js:95:1)
    at renderWithHooks (react-dom.development.js:16141:1)
    at updateForwardRef (react-dom.development.js:19968:1)
    at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:22391:1)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:4157:1)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:4206:1)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:4270:1)
    at beginWork$1 (react-dom.development.js:27243:1)
    at performUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js:26392:1)
    at workLoopSync (react-dom.development.js:26303:1)
Paper @ Paper.js:95
renderWithHooks @ react-dom.development.js:16141
updateForwardRef @ react-dom.development.js:19968
beginWork @ react-dom.development.js:22391
callCallback @ react-dom.development.js:4157
invokeGuardedCallbackDev @ react-dom.development.js:4206
invokeGuardedCallback @ react-dom.development.js:4270
beginWork$1 @ react-dom.development.js:27243
performUnitOfWork @ react-dom.development.js:26392
workLoopSync @ react-dom.development.js:26303
renderRootSync @ react-dom.development.js:26271
performConcurrentWorkOnRoot @ react-dom.development.js:25577
workLoop @ scheduler.development.js:266
flushWork @ scheduler.development.js:239
performWorkUntilDeadline @ scheduler.development.js:533
Paper.js:95 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '4')
    at Paper (Paper.js:95:1)
    at renderWithHooks (react-dom.development.js:16141:1)
    at updateForwardRef (react-dom.development.js:19968:1)
    at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:22391:1)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:4157:1)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:4206:1)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:4270:1)
    at beginWork$1 (react-dom.development.js:27243:1)
    at performUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js:26392:1)
    at workLoopSync (react-dom.development.js:26303:1)
Paper @ Paper.js:95
renderWithHooks @ react-dom.development.js:16141
updateForwardRef @ react-dom.development.js:19968
beginWork @ react-dom.development.js:22391
callCallback @ react-dom.development.js:4157
invokeGuardedCallbackDev @ react-dom.development.js:4206
invokeGuardedCallback @ react-dom.development.js:4270
beginWork$1 @ react-dom.development.js:27243
performUnitOfWork @ react-dom.development.js:26392
workLoopSync @ react-dom.development.js:26303
renderRootSync @ react-dom.development.js:26271
recoverFromConcurrentError @ react-dom.development.js:25689
performConcurrentWorkOnRoot @ react-dom.development.js:25589
workLoop @ scheduler.development.js:266
flushWork @ scheduler.development.js:239
performWorkUntilDeadline @ scheduler.development.js:533
react-dom.development.js:18525 The above error occurred in the <ForwardRef(Paper)> component:

    at Paper (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:7289:82)
    at http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:1154:66
    at AppBar (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:3530:83)
    at Header (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:209:19)
    at div
    at ThemeProvider (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:9466:5)
    at App (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:77:19)

Consider adding an error boundary to your tree to customize error handling behavior.
Visit https://reactjs.org/link/error-boundaries to learn more about error boundaries.
logCapturedError @ react-dom.development.js:18525
update.callback @ react-dom.development.js:18558
callCallback @ react-dom.development.js:13092
commitUpdateQueue @ react-dom.development.js:13113
commitLayoutEffectOnFiber @ react-dom.development.js:23204
commitLayoutMountEffects_complete @ react-dom.development.js:24461
commitLayoutEffects_begin @ react-dom.development.js:24447
commitLayoutEffects @ react-dom.development.js:24385
commitRootImpl @ react-dom.development.js:26651
commitRoot @ react-dom.development.js:26517
finishConcurrentRender @ react-dom.development.js:25731
performConcurrentWorkOnRoot @ react-dom.development.js:25648
workLoop @ scheduler.development.js:266
flushWork @ scheduler.development.js:239
performWorkUntilDeadline @ scheduler.development.js:533
Paper.js:95 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '4')
    at Paper (Paper.js:95:1)
    at renderWithHooks (react-dom.development.js:16141:1)
    at updateForwardRef (react-dom.development.js:19968:1)
    at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:22391:1)
    at beginWork$1 (react-dom.development.js:27219:1)
    at performUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js:26392:1)
    at workLoopSync (react-dom.development.js:26303:1)
    at renderRootSync (react-dom.development.js:26271:1)
    at recoverFromConcurrentError (react-dom.development.js:25689:1)
    at performConcurrentWorkOnRoot (react-dom.development.js:25589:1)
```

What should I do now?
Thank you.